# Non-separability of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

A Fock space constructed via a separable Hilbert space is separable, however the tensor product of a countable set of separable Hilbert spaces is not (infinite qbit chain). How is the previous statement correct, I thought the two spaces would be separable they seem to be quite literally the same.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: This might be better on a math site.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Prove that the tensor product of a countably infinite set of separable Hilbert spaces is not separable.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: I think that a countable product of seperable topological spaces *is* separable:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244427/. Who says that iot is not?

Comment: @mikestone thank you for the link that was the proof I was looking for. For the who says, slide 5 of https://relativity.phys.lsu.edu/ilqgs/barbero042115.pdf claims it